# How do I get my freelancing salary from the previous company?

Tags: salary, freelancing, company

Currently, I am working as a Software Developer in India. But till April 2017, I was working as a Content Writer in another company. After leaving that job, I took freelancing from that company for the Content Writing part and have continued the Freelancing since then. But in 2018, I started receiving my salary extremely late. Also, I came to know that the financial condition of that company has gone very bad.

For some personal reasons, I quit the Freelancing from that company at the mid of January itself and I came to know that company has closed the Freelancing operations for all the freelancers. But the disgusting fact was that the HR of that company hasn't paid any of the freelancers their January salary till yet. All of the freelancers including me have called the HR and the general manager more than 50 times but they fool us by playing a blame game.

Manager responds by saying that I am not responsible for your salary and you should talk to HR regarding that. HR always says that she have talked to the accounts department of company regarding our salary and we will soon receive our salary but that day has never arrived since last 2 months. We got the number of the person, who was the head of the accounts department of that company but after receiving calls regularly for a couple of days ago, that monster changed his number.

Now, I got the news that the employees of that company are being paid their salary on time. This bad condition is concerned only with the freelancers like us. Also, the HR and General Manager never responds to the emails.

Now, the only option left for us is to visit them in their office and to demand our salary by arguing with them. However, this also doesn't seems to be a good option because a similar incident happened in the past when I was working in that company and instead of giving the salary to the Freelancer, who visited that day, they called up the cops to arrest him, blaming him for threatening case.
Can anyone suggest what can I do to get back my salary?

Comment: Go to the police and case a file..............

Comment: Better yet, file a bankruptcy claim on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your contract, explain the situation to a lawyer, and then take this case to court. Ideally, talk with all the other freelancers who haven't been paid and start a case together.

Comment: Actually, the thing is that my remaining dues from them is around 2000-3000 Indian Rupees and hiring a lawyer in India for this matter will cost me more than 5000 Indian Rupees.

Comment: @DG4 if you're not willing to hire a lawyer, you're not getting any money from them. They made it pretty clear that they have no intention of paying you.

Comment: Consult the attorney anyway.  Find out if Indian law allows recovery of attorney's fees and court costs as well as actual damages.  Depending on the rules, the attorney MAY be willing to do this on contingency, in which case he doesn't get paid until and unless you get paid.

Answer (score 1):

Send them a registered letter (snail mail) demanding proper payment, with a reasonable deadline. The amount is about US$40 so you can only do so much, and it sounds like they are robbing Prajwal to pay Padam.

Do not go there alone and confront them, if they manage to provoke you or if they lie that you acted belligerent you will have no recourse and they may have multiple witnesses who claim to have felt threatened.